Autoflake prints unused imports/variables but doesn't remove them
I'm using the autoflake tool to remove unused imports and variables in a Python file, but while it prints that unused imports/variables are detected, it doesn't actually remove them from the file.
Here's the command I'm running:
autoflake --in-place --remove-unused-variables portal/reports.py

Printed Output:
portal/reports.py: Unused imports/variables detected

Despite the message indicating unused imports and variables, the file remains unchanged. I've confirmed that the file has unused imports and variables that should be removed.
Versions:

Django: 5.0.7
autoflake: 2.3.1
Python: 3.11
Ubuntu: 24.04

I also noticed this issue: when I try to install autoflake after turning off .venv in my Django app folder or anywhere in the OS, I get the following error.
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.12/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.

Has anyone encountered this issue? What could be causing it, and how can I fix it to properly remove unused imports and variables?

Yes, as it says, since Python-3.12, there is no "global" env anymore.

What is the content of portal/reports.py?

@16171413 It contains code for reporting from the database. This issue is occurring with all the files in my Django app.

Similar issue raised here https://github.com/PyCQA/autoflake/issues/215 does it help?

ok moved to answer

A similar issue was raised here and the OP was able to solve the issue by removing
[tool.autoflake]
check = true

in the pyproject.toml. See Remove unused imports not working in place.
